# ELFsh Inject Compiled C code into an existing binary

Tags: linux

I have hit a problem working with the ELFsh library, specifically when attempting to use the example in the testsuite which demonstrates [injecting compiled C code into an existing binary](http://www.eresi-project.org/browser/trunk/testsuite/elf/etrel_inject/etrel_original).

What I've done so far is:

- Checkout ELFsh from SVN (`svn checkout  http://svn.eresi-project.org/svn/trunk/ eresi`)
- `./env.sh, ./configure --enable-32-64 --enable-m64, make, sudo make install`. Also tried `sudo make install64`. After installing dependencies, the library built and installed fine.

`eresi/testsuite/elf/etrel_inject/etrel_original` contains the test I am interested in running. In there, I made a small change to the `Makefile`, which I believe has a small bug which is that `-m32` is not explicitly specified in the `all32` target which causes the result of `all32` and `all64` to be the same if compiled on a 64-bit system. Next:

- I ran `make` (builds everything okay)

Now, my understanding of what is supposed to happen is that there is a target `host.c` which is compiled to `hijackme32` and `hijackme64`. These are 32 and 64 bit binaries to which `rel.32.o` and `rel.64.o` are injected to respectively.

This injection can be performed in two ways in the test - through the ELFsh script (`relinject32.esh` and `relinject64.sh`) and through the C API (`relinject32` and `relinject64`).

Running `relinject32` results in:

```
[E] Unable to load object
```

Running `relinject64` results in:

```
[E] Unable to copy PLT
```

To get finer grained information about where the problem lies, I loaded up ELFsh interactively and went through the steps of `relinject32/64.esh` one by one. Both scripts fail on loading of the target:

```
(elfsh-0.82-b2-dev@local) load hijackme32



 [E] Cannot load object

(elfsh-0.82-b2-dev@local) load hijackme64


 [*] Sun Mar 18 02:49:04 2012 - New object loaded : hijackme64
Architecture EM_X86_64 : AMDx86-64 architecture not supported. No flowjack available.
 [E] Libmjollnir unsupported architecture
```

Oddly, attempting to load the 32-bit target with its full path results in a different error:

```
(elfsh-0.82-b2-dev@local) load /home/mike/Desktop/eresi/testsuite/elf/etrel_inject/etrel_original/hijackme32

Architecture EM_X86_64 : AMDx86-64 architecture not supported. No flowjack available.


 [E] Cannot load object
```

This is surprising because the OS produces:

```
mike@mike-linux:file hijackme32
hijackme32: ELF 32-bit LSB executable, Intel 80386, version 1 (SYSV), dynamically linked (uses shared libs), for GNU/Linux 2.6.15, not stripped
mike@mike-linux:file hijackme64
hijackme64: ELF 64-bit LSB executable, x86-64, version 1 (SYSV), dynamically linked (uses shared libs), for GNU/Linux 2.6.15, not stripped
```

---

The current system I am testing on is x86-64 Ubuntu.

My question is how do I get this test to run? Am I setting up the environment or building incorrectly?

---

I tried going on the IRC (preferred method of communication), but the project (and channel) seem pretty much dead now.

Comment: Eresi is a great project in my opinion, unfortunately it is pretty much dead - developers have to live from something :(